# The meaning implied by ことになった in this sentence

Tags: meaning, translation

> ZOOMを用いて重要な打ち合わせをすることになったが使ったことがない。

Since I couldn’t comprehend this sentence I tried using couple of auto translators and this is what both gave me:  “I’ve decided to use zoom for an important meeting but I don’t have any experience using it.”

I was wondering where in the sentence was “making a decision” implied; and from what I gathered it has something to do with the expression “ことになった”
But what exactly is the use and meaning of it? Or does it technically have another meaning which in this case when translated it is turned into “planning” or “making the decision”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“ことになった” is Passive.
In this case, you didn't decide to use zoom, rather it happens that you started to use zoom. In English, we normally use active sentences (we are praised to do so too) but in Japanese, the passive form is preferred.

ZOOMを用いて重要な打ち合わせをすることになったが使ったことがない。
We started to use zoom for important meetings, but I have never used it before. (the decision is made by the company, someone other than me)
～ことになる signifies natural development, not a decision as I've decided...

コロナの影響で、ほとんどの人はテレワークすることになった。
Due to Covid-19, many people started to do telework.

Hope it helps!